# Read Access of object to Anonymous users in private s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I am trying to write a bucket policy that will grant Only read access to everyone(public) but the bucket should remain private.
This is the policy I have came up with.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::this_is_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is access settings.(The Settings must remain this way)
[image]

But The problem continues, Objects still can not be accessed. I'm not supposed to use ACLs either.  I know I'm making a mistake here but I can't figure out how to solve this? any Thoughts and suggestions are highly appreciated. thank you for any help.

Comment: "will grant Only read access to everyone(public) but the bucket should remain private" - this does not make any sense. How it can be public and private at the same time? Can you clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean I want the users to be able to view the object of my bucket which is private. and just View them no any other action. i am trying to achieve object level flexibility here. if you know how to do it please help.

Comment: You have to disable the last option in your screenshot.

Comment: yes i have tried to do it at first. but it makes the whole bucket public. and i am not allowed to have a public bucket due to security reasons.

Comment: Sorry, but again you are not making any sense. Bucket is private or public. You can't have both at the same time. Make your choice or explain better what do you want to achive.

Comment: yes the bucket is Private. and there is a way to access private bucket objects too. but my problem here is the objects must be 'readable' to 'Everyone on the internet'. just READABLE nothing else. i'm sorry If i can't justify the problem correctly. I am newbie  in AWS.

Comment: `s3:GetObject` allows only read access. For it to work for everyone you must disable the last option as I said.

Comment: yes of course i know that is the way. i have tried and it had worked perfect with just one problem that it sticks the nice red public stamp on the bucket :). but as I said my org does not want public buckets.

Comment: Then you have a problem: you want a public bucket, your org does not want one, end of story, nothing we can do. Figure this out between you and your org.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Is there any better solution came yet?

Comment: @MuhaimenulIslam what I did was to make individual object public by enabling the object ACL to grant read access. While the bucket in question is still private. This way I managed to make objects readable.